# Socket opens a pipe but doesn't close it

Tags: java, linux, sockets, pipe, bufferedreader

I am listening a socket and have used a readLine() function.
If I see the number of file descriptors opened up by my program, I see that when I call the the readLine() function, something opens up two file descriptors (pipes). (It can be seen in /proc//fd)

If a socket timeout exception occurs, even after closing the Buffered Reader, the pipes remain opened.
How do I close it?

Here is my program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

// Test case code for file descriptor leak.
// The following should produce somewhere near 150 sockets in CLOSE_WAIT state.
// The problem appears to be in   sun.nio.ch.SocketAdapter.SocketInputStream.read(ByteBuffer);

public class TestClose implements Runnable {

public static final String SMTP_HOSTNAME = "10.10.10.59";

    public void run()
    {
    InetSocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress(SMTP_HOSTNAME, 5269);
            SocketChannel sChannel = null;
            Socket socket = null;
            String result = null;
             BufferedReader lineRdr = null;
             InputStreamReader is  = null;
            try
            {
                    sChannel = SocketChannel.open();
                    sChannel.socket().connect(sockAddr);


                    sChannel.socket().setSoTimeout(20000);
                    socket = sChannel.socket();

                    is = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                   lineRdr = new BufferedReader(is);



                    do
                    {
            // before performing the first readline the channel is unregistered
                            System.err.println("before first readline: isOpen = "+sChannel.isOpen()+" isRegistered="+sChannel.isRegistered());                                

                            result = lineRdr.readLine();                            

                            System.err.println("<- "+result);

            // after performing it is registered.
                            System.err.println("after first readline: isOpen = "+sChannel.isOpen()+" isRegistered="+sChannel.isRegistered());

                    } while(result != null && result.length() > 0 && result.matches("^[1-5][0-9]{2}-"));

                    if(result == null || result.length() == 0)
                    {
                            System.err.println("Received truncated response from SMTP server " + sockAddr.getHostName());
                            return;
                    }

                    // Tokenize the last line result
                    //
                    StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(result);
                    int rc = Integer.parseInt(t.nextToken());
                    if(rc != 220) return;

                    //
                    // Send the QUIT command causing the server side to close its end of the connection
                    //
                    String cmd = "QUIT\r\n";
                    socket.getOutputStream().write(cmd.getBytes());
                    System.err.println("-> "+cmd);
                    do
                    {
                            result = lineRdr.readLine();
                            System.err.println("<- "+result);
                    } while(result != null && result.length() > 0 && result.matches("^[1-5][0-9]{2}-"));

                    if(result == null || result.length() == 0)
                    {
                            System.err.println("Received truncated response from SMTP server " + sockAddr.getHostName());
                            return;
                    }

            }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("result "+result);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            finally
            {
        try {

                //socket.getInputStream().close();
               lineRdr.close();
               lineRdr = null;
               is.close();
            is = null;

               System.err.println("before close: isOpen = "+sChannel.isOpen()+" isRegistered="+sChannel.isRegistered());

            System.err.println("Closing SMTP socket channel "+sChannel);
            System.err.println("channel.socket().isConnected = "+ sChannel.socket().isConnected());
             System.err.println("channel.socket().isclose = "+ sChannel.socket().isClosed());
             System.err.println("channel.socket().isConnected = "+ sChannel.socket().isConnected());
            if (sChannel != null) {
                if(sChannel.socket().isClosed()== false){
                            sChannel.socket().shutdownOutput();
                     sChannel.socket().close();
                    }
                   // sChannel.shutdownOutput();
                    sChannel.close();
                    System.err.println("Closed SMTP socket channel "+sChannel);

                // The socket is still connected here.
                    System.err.println("channel.socket().isConnected = "+sChannel.socket().isConnected());
                    System.err.println("channel.socket().isclose = "+ sChannel.socket().isClosed());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println("Exception on close:");
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }

            return;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClose test = new TestClose();
    while(true) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
     // this bug seems only to appear if different threads are reading the channels
            Thread thread = new Thread(test);
        thread.start();
        try {thread.join(); } catch(InterruptedException e) {   }
    }

    System.err.println("Going to sleep.... run netstat -an | grep CLOSE_WAIT ");

            try { Thread.sleep(10000); } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I see that the readLine() function opens up two file descriptors
>   (pipes).

Yes, after socketTimeout is set with non zero value, SocketInputStream starts to use non-blocking read inside `readLine()` and can (if input is not already present in socket) open up to two pipes per reading thread.

> If a socket timeout exception occurs, even after closing the Buffered
>   Reader, the pipes remain opened. How do I close it?

You don't have to, in your case pipes would be closed after next GC, when Selectors (which hold file descriptors ids) would be closed by sun.misc.Cleaner. Cleaner class is based on [PhantomReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) and its cleanup is performed in ReferenceHandler thread.

Comment: So it would be more accurate to say that the *socket* opens the pipes.

Comment: It would be accurate to say that `Selector` opens the pipes, `Selector` instance is created via `SelectorProvider.openSelector()`, and `Socket` holds the instance of `SelectorProvider`. But I think it isn't correct to say `the socket opens the pipes.`. Anyway, imho this is unnecessary information, cause lots of details which don't make the whole picture clear are confusing.

Comment: In the answer I was pointing to `SocketAdaptor.SocketInputStream` which decides to create Selector (and in this way open pipes). Also I described conditions depending on which it will do so. After this I answered the question. _I hope this was helpfull_.